# Error during heasoft installtion

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to installing the software called HEASoft6.13 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I am using the source code and it configured successfully (using `./configure` command). In the next step, I tried to run the command `make`, it showed the following error. If anyone could point out what went wrong?

Thanks in advance

```
make[8]: [tclreadline.lo] Error 1
make[8]: Leaving directory `/home/jithesh/softwares/xraysoft/heasoft-6.13/tcltk  /tclreadline'
make[7]: [subdir-tclreadline] Error 2
make[7]: Leaving directory `/home/jithesh/softwares/xraysoft/heasoft-6.13/tcltk/BUILD_DIR'
make[6]: [build-tclreadline] Error 2
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/jithesh/softwares/xraysoft/heasoft-6.13/tcltk/BUILD_DIR'
make[5]: [hd-std-all-subdirs] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/jithesh/softwares/xraysoft/heasoft-6.13/tcltk/BUILD_DIR'
make[4]: [all-subdirs] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/jithesh/softwares/xraysoft/heasoft-6.13/tcltk/BUILD_DIR'
make[3]: [hd-std-all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/jithesh/softwares/xraysoft/heasoft-6.13/tcltk/BUILD_DIR'
make[2]: [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/jithesh/softwares/xraysoft/heasoft-6.13/tcltk/BUILD_DIR'
make[1]: [tcltk] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jithesh/softwares/xraysoft/heasoft-6.13/BUILD_DIR'
make: [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed for the latest version of `HEASOFT 6.15.1`, after April-2014.

The error is due to incompatibilities between the `libreadline` version available in the trusty repositories and the one required by the `HEASOFT` installation scripts.
If you have a reason to use the `6.13` version, contact the [`HEASOFT` help-desk](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/ftoolshelp) and they can send you a patch fix.